# Is Kotlin 1.2.20 compatible with spring boot 1.5.9

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring boot project with kotlin 1.2.10 and every time I try to switch the Kotlin version to 1.2.20 in my pom.xml my Junit related to the data contained in data.sql are falling. The other tests are still ok. So I guess the data.sql isn't loaded properly.

This is one of the test falling :

```
   @Test
    fun findOne() {
        val child= repository.findOne(1L)
        Assertions.assertThat(child.firstname)
                .isEqualTo("firstname")
    }
```

This the code of the repository :

```
internal interface ChildRepository : JpaRepository<Child, Long>{

    @Query("select c from Child c where c.daycare.id=:idDaycare")
    fun findAllByDaycare(@Param("idDaycare") id: Long): MutableList<Child>

    @Query("select c from Child c where c.id=:id and c.daycare.id=:idDaycare")
    fun findOneByIdByDaycare(@Param("id") id: Long,@Param("idDaycare") idDaycare: Long): Child
}
```

Adding the stack on the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ablx.daycare.backend.repository.ChildRepositoryTest.findOne(ChildRepositoryTest.kt:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Adding entity :

```
@Entity
internal data class Child(
        @field: Id @field: GeneratedValue var id: Long = 0, //Primary Key
        var firstname: String = "",
        var lastname: String = "",
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "daycare")
        var daycare: Daycare = Daycare(),
        @get:JsonIgnore
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        var sumups: List<Sumup> = emptyList()
)
{
        override fun toString(): String {
                return "Child(id=$id, firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', daycare=$daycare)"
        }
}
```

The spring repo doesn't find my entity and as soon as I switch back to 1.2.10. The test is ok.

Should I modify something when I switch to Kotlin 1.2.20?

Turning kotlin.compiler.incremental to false in my pom.xml made the build ok on kotlin 1.2.20. Don't understand why though.

Switching back to Kotlin 1.2.10 solved my problem for now.

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: No runtime error just the test failing. I am gonna add it to the original post.

Comment: Do you have any plugins like kotlin-jpa?

Comment: Nope. I have only kotlin-stdlib-jre8 and kotlin-reflect.

Comment: Can you post your entity class?

Comment: I posted the entity. I am pretty sure it's not the problem because I tried to reduce the project with only the entity to reproduce the problem without success.

Comment: Finally I was able to reproduce the pb in a minimal project and I published it to my GitHub https://github.com/mikrethor/testkotlin_1_2_20/